# Como exibir o dados cadastrado em outra pagina

Tags: php, mysql

Olá amigos como poderia fazer com que os dados cadastrados apareça em outra pagina em uma tabela ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" onSubmit="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sistema de Inventário</legend><br />

            <label class="borda">Setor: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" name="setor" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Usuário:</label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">O/S :</label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" name="os" size="30" required><br /><br />

            <label class="borda">Hd : </label>
            <input  class="form_inp"type="text"  name="hd" size="30" required><br />                        
            <hr />          
            <label class="borda">Memória:</label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="memoria" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Processador: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="processador"  name="processador" size="30" required><br /><br />
            <hr />
            <label class="borda">Cd/Dvd: </label>
            <select class="form_inp"  name="cd"> 
                <option value="Sim">Sim</option> 
                <option value="Não">Não</option> 
            </select>

            <br />

            <label class="borda">Placa Mãe: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="placam" name="placam" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">HostName: </label>
            <input class="form_inp"type="text" id="host" name="host" size="30" required><br /><br />

            <label class="borda">Monitor/Patrimônio/Marca/Modelo: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="monitor" name="monitor" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Nobreak/Patrimônio/Marca/: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="nobreak" name="nobreak" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Placa de Rede : </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="placar" name="placar" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Placa de Vídeo: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="placav" name="placav" size="30" required><br />

            <hr />
            <input type="submit" style="float: right;" value="Cadastrar" >
            <input type="reset" style="float: right;" value="Limpar">

        </fieldset>
    </form>

       <?php

        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


        $servidor = "localhost";
        $usuario = "root";
        $senha = "";
        $dbname = "cadastro";

        //Criar a conexao
        $link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "cadastro");
        if($link->connect_errno){
             echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
             exit();
         }

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                print_r($_POST);
                $setor=$_POST['setor'];
                $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
                $hd=$_POST['hd'];
                $memoria=$_POST['memoria'];
                $processador=$_POST['processador'];
                $cd=$_POST['cd'];
                $placam=$_POST['placam'];
                $host=$_POST['host'];
                $monitor=$_POST['monitor'];
                $nobreak=$_POST['nobreak'];
                $placar=$_POST['placar'];
                $placav=$_POST['placav'];
                $sql="INSERT INTO setor(setor,usuario,hd,memoria,processador,cd,placam,host,monitor,nobreak,placar,placav) VALUES('$setor','$usuario','$hd','$memoria','$processador','$cd','$placam','$host','$monitor','$nobreak','$nobreak','$placav')";
                $resultado_cadastro = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: [Como não fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1).

Comment: Tá difícil entender...

Comment: tem essa tela de cadastro e quero ver o que foi cadastrado em outra pagina.

Comment: Recuperar os dados do último registro e mostrar na outra página não funcionaria?

Comment: Sim , não só o ultimo registo mas sim todos .Como faço @ShutUpMagda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que os dados que você quer listar já estão salvos em um banco de dados, não é muito difícil.

Crie a nova página, faça a sua conexão com o banco de dados e, em seguida, execute a sua query já pegando os resultados. Exemplo (usando mysql_query e considerando que você vá usar PHP):

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lista de Cadastros</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Estes são os cadastros</h1>
        <?php //A CONEXÃO COM O BANCO VAI AQUI... ?>
        <?php  $result = mysql_query(SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3..., campoN FROM nomeDaTabela); ?>
        <table>
            <tr>

                <th>Dado 1</th>
                <th>Dado 2</th>
                <th>Dado 3</th>
                <th>Dado N</th>
            </tr>
            <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row['campo1']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['campo2']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['campo3']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['campoN']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>`

Obs: mysql_query está depreciada. Procure usar PDO. Há muitos tutoriais na internet ensinando como fazer.